# how to smoothscroll recyclerview by a random place between two item in a proper time

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I want to smoothscroll the recyclerview to a **random place** between two items after clicking a button.
 By using

```
smoothScrollBy(dx , dy)
```

I can get the right place but cant control the speed/duration(too fast,i hope to make it slow).

By using

```
smoothScrollToPosition()
```

and implementing `calculateSpeedPerPixel()` i can control the speed but cant got the right place (cant stop  between two items).

in fact i am looking for a way to do the same work as

```
ListView.smoothScrollBy(int distance, int duration).
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Mark Allison has a blog post series that explains how you can customise and control the duration when you want to scroll to a position.

https://blog.stylingandroid.com/scrolling-recyclerview-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use this method with a custom interpolator:
[`smoothScrollBy(int, int, Interpolator)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#smoothScrollBy(int,%20int,%20android.view.animation.Interpolator))

You can for example use an Accelerate Interpolator with a different value.
Try varying the number to see what suits you:

```
smoothScrollBy(dx , dy, new AccelerateInterpolator(2));
```

Comment: this method seems only change the animation but not the duration of scrolling . thank you all the same